# Java: Hibernate - Query to delete from multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have two tables connected by a foreign key with a one to many relation.

In entity A I have the following:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade( {
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
@OneToMany(mappedBy="monitoredFlight", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<bTable> BTable = new ArrayList<BTable>();
```

Now I try to delete from table A with a bulk delete query:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("delete from A where originDateTime<:date");
```

and I get the foreign key constraint error. I decided to do the delete with a join just as I would in mysql, so I changed it to:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("delete from A join BTable where originDateTime<:date");
```

and I got a syntax error. I have tried several combination with or without join and nothing works; any ideas?

I am using mysql for the database and java for the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a native query, the following should work in mysql:

```
delete a , b from a inner join b on a.id=b.a_id where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a foreign key with the parameter **on delete cascade** so that when the key it references is deleted all rows that it is a foreign key on are also deleted.

Comment: i have that allerady but i want to do a massive deletion and not a one by one deletion.

Comment: What do you mean?  Every row that is deleted in Table A will subsequently cause a cascade delete on Table B for any rows that share the foreign key - hence you won't get the constraint error, instead all the foreign key mapped rows in Table B will also be deleted.